# Best practice when accesessing derived classes in a QList

Tags: c++, qt, polymorphism, downcast, qlist

I have a base model where I have implemented the virtual members of QAbstractItemModel. I then use my base model in my project as needed by deriving new classes with specifics.

```
class BaseModel : public QAbstractItemModel{
    public:
        ...

    protected:
        QList<BaseItem*> list;
}

class DerivedModel : public BaseModel{
    public:
        ...
}

class DerivedItem : public BaseItem{
    public:
        ...
}
```

My derived model uses `DerivedItem` objects to store data which have some specifics that `BaseItem` doesn't have. They are stored in `list`. Methods in `BaseModel` uses objects in `list` as well.

My issues is because of this I have to type cast every time I access objects from `list` in the derived model. And I can't use macros like `foreach`.

Is there any tips or tricks I can use in this circumstance that will enable me to use macros and prevent me from type casting every time I access items from the `list`. Or is there another method (better practice) when making a common class to later derive from.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

when `BaseItem` has virtual methods and `DerivedItem` does only overwrite the existing members of `BaseItem` you should be able to call

```
foreach(BaseItem* item, list){
    item->foo();
}
```

because of polymorphism, `item->foo()` will call `DerivedItem::foo()` if it is of that type otherwise it will call `BaseItem::foo()`

Comment: My issue is the members of `DerivedItem` I want to call doesn't exist in `BaseItem`. `BaseItem`only has general members that's needed by `BaseModel` where `DerivedItem` has more specifics.

Comment: then you might think if the design could be improved or you cast the items as you use them.